# How i can to add to the location in this json?

Tags: android, json

How i can to add the "location" in this json?

it's give me "null", here is simple of the code of the json............................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

```js
{
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "results" : [
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 31.8004863,
               "lng" : 35.155975
            },
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 31.80183612989272,
                  "lng" : 35.15732482989272
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 31.79913647010727,
                  "lng" : 35.15462517010727
               }
            }
         },
         "icon" : "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/restaurant-71.png",
         "id" : "74f5b809b62fcf35766480a616de5001c470247e",
         "name" : "בורגרס בר | Burgers Bar",
         "opening_hours" : {
            "open_now" : true
         },
         "photos" : [
            {
               "height" : 4048,
               "html_attributions" : [
                  "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/103176736009300448033/photos\"\u003eינון בר ישועה\u003c/a\u003e"
               ],
               "photo_reference" : "CmRaAAAAcoAMqy_VbKFHSy1npn6QMLAoFxaM7Jlc-hS2PtiSopKPizvIEsErjCB6VIW3HrWeiXfOX2npcp8uXHdQ4tALfu6B9w_gbPqJFfknqEfHjKqMY2voYDljGZ8xhXyC3F7TEhD5fejHnVYdp4dk-hnwR1qiGhTlEWS0jlKa3vFdz3FhX4MAUZAUiA",
               "width" : 3036
            }
         ],
         "place_id" : "ChIJy7TbP-TWAhUR5rzxuO1Vi9g",
         "plus_code" : {
            "compound_code" : "R524+59 מבשרת ציון",
            "global_code" : "8G3QR524+59"
         },
         "rating" : 4.2,
         "reference" : "ChIJy7TbP-TWAhUR5rzxuO1Vi9g",
         "scope" : "GOOGLE",
         "types" : [ "restaurant", "point_of_interest", "food", "establishment" ],
         "vicinity" : "האורן 47, מבשרת ציון"
      },
```

My class containing the json

```
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class MapModel implements Serializable {

private double lat;
private double lng;
private String vicinity;
private String name;
private String id;
private String icon;

JSONObject json;
JSONObject loc;

{
    try {
        loc = json.getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location");
        lat = loc.getDouble("lat");
        lng = loc.getDouble("lng");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public MapModel(String name, String vicinity, double lat, double lng, String icon) {
    this.vicinity = vicinity;
    this.name = name;
    this.lat = lat;
    this.lng = lng;
    this.icon = icon;
}


public double getLng() {
    return lng;
}

public void setLng(double lng) {
    this.lng = lng;
}

public String getIcon() {
    return icon;
}

public void setIcon(String icon) {
    this.icon = icon;
}

public double getLat() {
    return lat;
}

public void setLat(double location) {
    this.lat = location;
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getVicinity() {
    return vicinity;
}

public void setVicinity(String formatted_address) {
    this.vicinity = formatted_address;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

}
```

Comment: what are you trying to do exactly? what do you mean by "add the location"?

Comment: @inavda  i want to add the "lat" and "lng" to show in my listview and i succeed add "name" and "vicinity" to show in my listview but i can't add "location" in this json, it's show me "null" i think because "lat" and "lng" have 3 times here

Comment: Could you show us the code you have to extract them?

Comment: @inavda  bro the code not important if you can read my quetion again to understand what i mean it's be a great :)

Comment: The code is actually very important... It'll help us know what *you've tried* and what json library you might be using, and no, it is not important they are in three distinct objects

Comment: @cricket_007  i post my class man

Comment: I'm not seeing it

Comment: @cricket_007  i add now

Comment: Please see my updated answer

Answer (score -1):

You'll want to use this method to add to a JSON

> JSONObject
>
> put(String name, Object value)

If you're getting null, then you're literally putting a null object

However, you already have location, so not clear what your ultimate goal is...

Here, you can see I am parsing your existing JSON

```
 String s = // not clear where this is coming from 
 MapModel m = new MapModel(); // building this object 
 try {
     JSONObject json = new JSONObject(s);
    JSONObject loc = json.getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location"):
    int lat = loc.getDouble("lat");
    int lng = loc.getDouble("lng");

    // And then assign the data 
    m.setLat(lat);  m.setLng(lng);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} 
// load m into some UI elements
```

Don't put this code in your MapModel. Put it immediately after wherever you got that JSON string from

Comment: i post my class i think need get you code, please check to me please

Comment: I don't know what you posted, or how you are parsing your JSON using that... This code goes immediately after you have your JSON string parsed into a JSONObject called `json`